# How to set max file upload size and allow only certain file types on PHP upload?

Tags: php, file-upload, max

I made a PHP upload file script. Now, I don't want people uploading files that are huge and I don't want them to upload PHP files either. Here's my current PHP script:

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "files/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
    $length = 10;
    $characters = '123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $string="";
    for($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
$pos = strrpos(basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']), ".");
$ext = str_split(basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']), $pos);
$target_path = $target_path.$string.$ext[1]; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "<h2>Your file has been uploaded!</h2><br /><p>Your file has been uploaded successfully. <a href='".$target_path."'>Click here</a> to see the file you uploaded.
    <br /><br /><br />
    <h2>A link to your file</h2><br />The full link to your file is:
    <br /><br />
    <code>http://www.americaspoeticsoul.com/extras/upload/".$target_path."</code></p>";
} else{
    echo "<span class='error'>There was an error uploading the file, please try again.</span>";
}
?>
```

How would I set a max file upload size and allow only certain file types such as only JPEGs, GIFs, PNGs, and HTML files?

Thanks in advance,
Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the file size using `$_FILES['uploadedfile']["size"]`. The client-supplied file type is available in `...["type"]`.

But for your code you will want to probe the `$ext` variable against a whitelist (just looking for extensions to forbid might not be a good idea):

```
if (in_array($ext, array("jpeg","gif","png","txt","html"))) {
    if (move_uploaded_file(...
```

At this point it might be advisable to consider a readymade helper class/script for all the upload checking. Your code is quite unreadable already.

Comment: I never tried this but if I upload an arbitrary file after renaming its extension to `.jpg`?

Comment: Thanks, mario. I'll see if this works. I'm new to PHP so I might have some trouble just getting what you provided above into my code. :/

Comment: @Kumar I didn't know an arbitrary file would work with the `.jpg` extension?

Comment: @Kumar That's indeed what still poses a problem. But at least a .jpg extension on the server will not trigger CGI execution or the PHP interpreter to invoke on that uploaded file. NTL appropriate `Options` should be set via `.htaccess` in the upload folder. (Additionally. A more elaborate upload script would check for magic bytes and verify some file types at least.)

Comment: Well @nathan think about it, I am just hell bent on breaking the system, I take a random file and rename it to `picture.jpg` and then upload it, will the `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['type']` recognise it on the basis of extension or the file content?

Comment: @mario Would I wrap the `if (in_array($ext, array("jpeg","gif","png","txt","html"))) {` around the part where it displays a message when the file has been uploaded?

Comment: @Nathan: As shown. Before the `move_uploaded_file`. Otherwise it's probably too late to check.

Comment: @Kumar I don't know if the `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['type']` will be based on file extension or file content. Hopefully the file content.

Comment: @nathan, just checked in an existing CI setup by uploading an XML file renamed as jpg, it doesn't work :-) So it seems browser does send the correct mime type based on file content rather than extension :-)

Comment: @mario But I  just tried this and now it seems that the echoes don't work when I wrapped the if around the `if (move_uploaded_file(...` as shown above. It wasn't showing "Your file has been uploaded successfully!" or anything, like it broke the whole `<?php ?>` part. Any ideas on why this wont work?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't start sentences with conjunctives.

First, the content:

The short answer is that you cannot restrict the type of file people upload.

A longer answer is that you can check the type of file people have uploaded and discard it if does not meet your requirements. Note that checking the mimetype or file extension supplied by the user does not provide very much protection. There's a good discussion of the problem and [how to solve it here](http://www.scanit.be/uploads/php-file-upload.pdf).

Next the size:

See Example #1 on http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
Note that not all browsers respect the MAX_FILE_SIZE input tag. File size will also be constrained by the php.ini directives listed on that page and the constraints on request and POST sizes and timeouts configured on your webserver.

BTW, your method of generating filenames is rather verbose. Using uniqid() will probably be a lot faster with a lot less code. Using md5_file() will have the same benefits and prevent duplication.

Comment: Get over it kid, its just a conjunction. Stop Being so Picky

Comment: @symcbean This isn't English class, this is a forum for developers, meaning I shouldn't be corrected with how I word my question. Thanks for the answer but I'm pretty sure PHP has a way to restrict what type of files are aloud. Regarding the size, the `MAZ_FILE_SIZE` input tag can be changed by the user using Developer Tools in Chrome and they will be able to changer the max file upload to what they want if I use that. I rather use PHP as it would be more secure. I'll check out your links that you posted.