# .rar, .zip files MIME Type

Tags: php, zip, mime-types, rar

I'm developing a simple php upload script, and users can upload only ZIP and RAR files.

What MIME types I should use to check `$_FILES[x][type]`? (a complete list please)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set max file upload size and allow only certain file types on PHP upload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950920/how-to-set-max-file-upload-size-and-allow-only-certain-file-types-on-php-upload)

Comment: I want to allow all compressed files alone(rar,zip,tar.gz,jar etc), what is the procedure?

Answer (score 314, accepted):

The answers from freedompeace, Kiyarash and Sam Vloeberghs:

```
.rar    application/vnd.rar, application/x-rar-compressed, application/octet-stream
.zip    application/zip, application/octet-stream, application/x-zip-compressed, multipart/x-zip
```

I would do a check on the file name too. Here is how you could check if the file is a RAR or ZIP file. I tested it by creating a quick command line application.

```
<?php

if (isRarOrZip($argv[1])) {
    echo 'It is probably a RAR or ZIP file.';
} else {
    echo 'It is probably not a RAR or ZIP file.';
}

function isRarOrZip($file) {
    // get the first 7 bytes
    $bytes = file_get_contents($file, FALSE, NULL, 0, 7);
    $ext = strtolower(substr($file, - 4));

    // RAR magic number: Rar!\x1A\x07\x00
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR
    if ($ext == '.rar' and bin2hex($bytes) == '526172211a0700') {
        return TRUE;
    }

    // ZIP magic number: none, though PK\003\004, PK\005\006 (empty archive), 
    // or PK\007\008 (spanned archive) are common.
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)
    if ($ext == '.zip' and substr($bytes, 0, 2) == 'PK') {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Notice that it still won't be 100% certain, but it is probably good enough.

```
$ rar.exe l somefile.zip
somefile.zip is not RAR archive
```

But even WinRAR detects non RAR files as SFX archives:

```
$ rar.exe l somefile.srr
SFX Volume somefile.srr
```

Comment: multipart/x-zip is a valid mimetype for .zip as well ( PKZIP archive )

Comment: actually there's another MIME TYPE for zip, and that's: `application/x-zip-compressed`

Comment: This won't guarantee you a `zip` or `rar` file at all. According to the [WC3 specifications](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) this will be intrepreted as: *"I prefer a `application/zip`|`application/x-rar-compressed` content type, but if you cannot deliver this an `application/octet-stream` (file stream) is also fine".*

Comment: Here is a usefull list of mime types with .zip among others: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

Comment: How in the world could `multipart/x-zip` possibly be valid? It's not multi-part. The SitePoint list contains many inaccurate MIME types and it's far from complete. The official [IANA Media Types registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#W3C) isn't (nor will it likely ever be) 100% complete.

Comment: Although a splendid solution now, not a very sustainable one. Who knows how the header might change or other new header content might be added in the future.

Comment: The headers are fixed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR_(file_format)

Comment: Since WinRAR version 5 there is a new file format for RAR archives available. To differentiate between them a new header is used: `'526172211a070100'`

Answer (score 49):

### For upload:

An official list of mime types can be found at [The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) . According to their list `Content-Type` header for `zip` is `application/zip`.

The media type for `rar` files, registered at IANA in 2016, is `application/vnd.rar` (see https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.rar). The mime-type value, `application/x-rar-compressed`, was used before that and is still commonly used even though it is marked as deprecated in the document above.

`application/octet-stream` means as much as: *"I send you a file stream and the content of this stream is not specified"* (so it is true that it can be a `zip` or `rar` file as well). The server is supposed to detect what the actual content of the stream is.

**Note:** For upload it is not safe to rely on the mime type set in the `Content-Type` header. The header is set on the client and can be set to any random value. Instead you can use [the php file info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) functions to detect the file mime-type on the server.

---

### For download:

If you want to download a `zip` file and nothing else you should only set one single `Accept` header value. Any additional values set will be used as a fallback in case the server cannot satisfy your in the `Accept` header requested mime-type.

According to the [WC3 specifications](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) this:

```
application/zip, application/octet-stream
```

will be intrepreted as: *"I prefer a `application/zip` mime-type, but if you cannot deliver this an `application/octet-stream` (a file stream) is also fine".*

So only a single:

```
application/zip
```

Will guarantee you a `zip` file (or a `406 - Not Acceptable` response in case the server is unable to satisfy your request).

Answer (score 7):

You should not trust `$_FILES['upfile']['mime']`, check MIME type by yourself. For that purpose, you may use [`fileinfo` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php), enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0.

```
  $fileInfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $fileMime = $fileInfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']);
  $validMimes = array( 
    'zip' => 'application/zip',
    'rar' => 'application/x-rar',
  );

  $fileExt = array_search($fileMime, $validMimes, true);
  if($fileExt != 'zip' && $fileExt != 'rar')
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
```

NOTE: Don't forget to enable the extension in your `php.ini` and restart your server:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Answer (score 4):

I see many answer reporting for zip and rar the Media Types `application/zip` and `application/x-rar-compressed`, respectively.

While the former matching is correct,  for the latter  IANA reports here https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.rar that for rar `application/x-rar-compressed` is a deprecated alias name and instead `application/vnd.rar` is the official one.
So, right Media Types from IANA in 2020 are:

1. `zip`: `application/zip`
2. `rar`: `application/vnd.rar`

Comment: Well, not sure about that. Their entry about zip is from 1993...

Comment: @Simpleton not sure that .zip has application/zip? Not sure I've hot your point, but if so why should a Media Type that has been marked as official change over the time? There is no expiration date. Maybe the file can become obsolete.

Comment: You're right, they don't expire unless they are explicitly made obsolete by something new. But IANA doesn't even mention those other zip mime types. Where do they come from? Why do they exist? How do they relate to the official "application/zip"? Perhaps IANA just neglected to update their info? How can we be sure?

Comment: Your 5 year later answer is virtually the same as my answer; same link to Iana, and same conclusion about the mime-types.

Answer (score 0):

In [a linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100445/zip-file-content-type-for-http-request), there's some Objective-C code to get the mime type for a file URL. I've created a Swift extension based on that Objective-C code to get the mime type:

```
import Foundation
import MobileCoreServices

extension URL {
    var mimeType: String? {
        guard self.pathExtension.count != 0 else {
            return nil
        }

        let pathExtension = self.pathExtension as CFString
        if let preferredIdentifier = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension, nil) {
            guard let mimeType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(preferredIdentifier.takeRetainedValue(), kUTTagClassMIMEType) else {
                return nil
            }
            return mimeType.takeRetainedValue() as String
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

As extension might contain more or less that three characters the following will test for an extension regardless of the length of it.

Try this:

```
$allowedExtensions = array( 'mkv', 'mp3', 'flac' );

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES[$file]["name"]);
$extension = strtolower(end($temp));

if( in_array( $extension, $allowedExtensions ) ) { ///
```

to check for all characters after the last '.'

Comment: It is very unfortunate but there is no guarantee that the mime type conventions illustrated by that other answers is observed by specific OS / browser combos. Really the only thing you can be sure of are file extension, unfortunately.