# PHP allowed zip mimetypes

Tags: php, mime-types

I know (from the answer to this question: [.rar, .zip files MIME Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977544/rar-zip-files-mime-type)) that that most people check zip files in PHP as `application/zip` or `application/octet-stream`, but I have a couple of questions about this:

- is it safe just to check for `application/octet-stream` (given that `application/octet-stream` can be used to describe many more file types than just zip!).  I know I could check the file in other ways too, but thought I should try and keep everything as simple as possible
- I've tried to check for as many different actual zip types as possible; but, there are some which give some unexpected results.  I've found 1 for which the mime-type is `application/x-external-editor`, but PHP has problems dealing with it (although the only error I get is `Warning: ZipArchive::close() [ziparchive.close]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object`) - is this documented anywhere?  Is there a list of actual `x-` mimetypes which PHP can cope with?

**Edit**

In answer to the questions below:

- I'm checking the mime type by using `$_FILES['fileatt']['type']`, but using `mime_content_type()` gives the same result.  Different zip files seem to be any one of the following: `'application/zip'`, `'application/x-compressed'`, `'application/x-zip-compressed'`, `'application/x-compressed'`, `'multipart/x-zip'`.  I didn't understand why I got an error when the mime type was detected as being `application/x-external-editor`.
- I have got the zip extension installed, and I am extracting all the files from the zip files when they are uploaded. I hadn't thought about checking the error.

I have also found another thing I don't quite understand: when I use the following code with a file which PHP reads as `application/x-external-editor`:

```
if($zip->open($_FILES[fileatt]['tmp_name'])===TRUE)
{
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

prints "error", but checking the file type as

```
$res = $zip->open($_FILES[fileatt]['tmp_name']);
if($res)
{
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

prints "success"; in this code, I assume that the boolean is effectively using `==`, not `===`, but why should this make a difference?

The error:

```
$res = $zip->open($_FILES[fileatt]['tmp_name']);
if($res===TRUE)
{
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo $res;
}
```

prints `19` - which error (https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php) does 19 refer to?!

Comment: in answer to your first question: no, it's not safe and it won't tell you anything about the file. How are you checking this, different zip files shouldn't give you different results unless they really are zip files. PHP can handle anything given the right library. Show your code on how you're detecting the mime type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never trust the mime type, this can be easily spoofed by the client.  They could submit an exe and give it a mime type of `text/plain` if they wanted to.

All zip files begin with a standard local file header signature (0x04034b50) so you could check that the first 4 bytes of the file match the zip signature bytes.  See the [PKZIP Appnote](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) for more details.

If you have the [zip extension](http://php.net/zip) enabled, you can go even further and attempt to open and read the zip to make sure it is a fully valid zip file.

Something like this works well:

```
$zip = zip_open('/path/to/file.zip');
if (is_int($zip)) {
    echo "Error $zip encountered reading the file, is it a valid zip?";
} else {
    echo "Thanks for uploading a valid zip file!";
}
```

`zip_open` returns a resource if opened successfully, otherwise an integer representing the error that occurred reading the file.

**EDIT:** To elaborate on some of your questions:

About `application/octet-stream`: This is as you said, a very generic type.  This just means any file that contains 8-bit data which is basically everything and anything.  `application/zip` is the de-facto standard mime-type, but some clients will use other values as you have discovered.  Also given the fact that a client can easily spoof any file type to use `application/zip` I wouldn't rely on `$_FILES['fileatt']['type']` since it can be anything.

AFIK, `mime_content_type()` simply looks at the file extension and maps it to a mime type from a [mime.types](http://servers.digitaldaze.com/extensions/mimetypes/mime.types.txt) file on the system or built into PHP.  If someone put a `.zip` extension on an `exe` file it would still register as `application/zip`.  I beleive certain extensions may examine the file header.

`Zip::open()` returns `TRUE` if the file was opened successfully, or an integer error code.  Therefore, `==` will give you a false positive on an error because any non-zero integer will evaluate to true using `==` since it will cast a non-zero integer to `TRUE`.  If you are going to check the return from `Zip::open` you should always use `$res === true` in order to check for success.  You can find the meanings of the error codes [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php) in the comment at the bottom of the page.

Bottom Line:  Since you said you are already extracting the zip, it may be less of a bother to validate based on the mime type, but instead it would be easier to just attempt to open the file and go based on the return value of `open`.  If it returns true, you can figure the file is a valid zip (there could of course be errors later in the file, but they at least uploaded something resembling a zip file).

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I've updated my question with some more info too.. :)

Comment: @ChrisW  I just updated the answer, hopefully that addresses your questions more.

Comment: thanks very much.  1 more quick (although probably stupid!) question: `Zip::open` apparently returns a `resource` or an integer according to the docs.  The `===` operator checks for type as well as equality, but why is a resouce the same type as the boolean value `true` if an integer isn't?

Comment: Yeah that is confusing, but the object oriented interface returns boolean true on successful open and int on failure, and the procedural interface returns a resource (`=== true` will not work) on success and integer on failure.