# Upload form not displaying 'ok' after 'if(!empty($name))"

Tags: php, html, upload

Ok guys, I've looked around everywhere and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. The please choose file triggers but the Ok. does noes not when a file is choosen. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        //$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        //$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

        //$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        if (isset($name)){
            if(!empty($name)){
                echo 'OK.';
            }
            else{
                echo 'Please choose a file.';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type = "submit" value="Submit"  name="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the value of $name?
Can you echo $name to check it?

Comment: when I write echo in front of $name = ... it doesn't echo anything

Comment: You should use ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) instead of isset($name)

Comment: tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: also if the isset($name) is not working why would the else be firing the echo 'Please choose a file'; code

Comment: Put this in your code and paste here the output

print_r($_FILES)

Comment: i put print_r($FILES); under all of the var declarations and the only time it fires is when I do not have a file set "Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) ) Please choose a file."

to @Fred-ii- 

     <html>
     <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <input type="file" name="file">
     <input type = "submit" value="Submit"  name="submit">
     </form>
     </html>

Comment: In tests that i made, i put print_r($_FILES) before "if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {" line and it show some information. Did you put it in this place too?

Comment: In this tests, are you submitting some file to this php script?

Comment: Try to post a file by your file input and then watch this print_r($_FILES)

Comment: ^It gives me the same output.

Comment: before I was trying to use .img and .mp3 files now I tried using a .torrent file and this was the output "Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => [kickasstorrent.720pdownload.com]dance.essentials.2015.armada.music.2015.320kbps.torrent [type] => application/x-bittorrent [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php1494.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 19322 ) ) OK."

Comment: it works with pdf's as well but not .zip's I'm really confused

Comment: Ok. So, note that the index "size" of the array is > 0.
Use this validation to see if the post has a file.

if (isset($_FILES["file"] && $_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0

Comment: Me too. Let me search about it

Comment: Please, paste here your <form> tag

Comment: <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type = "submit" value="Submit"  name="submit">
</form>
</html>

Comment: What is the value of attribute "enctype" of your form?

Comment: Ok, just change "multipart/form-data" to "application/x-compressed" and upload the zip again.

Comment: Check print_r one more time plz

Comment: when I try to upload a zip it still prints out 'array()' after I changed the enctype. I'm mainly trying to upload mp3's

Comment: and if you upload a mp3, is this works?

Comment: See the best answer on this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851534/php-file-upload-wont-accept-zip-files

Comment: still having trouble

Comment: I've figured out that the files are too large. How can I increase the MAX limit to about 250 megabytes?

Answer (score 1):

If a file is not present the `$_FILES['file']['name']` is not set.

```
if (isset($name)) {}
```

Does never fire.

Comment: the else fires correctly, and $name is set to $_FILES['file'][name']

Comment: $_FILES["file"]["name"] should not be set when there is no file. But try var_dump() if it somehow contains something.