# ZIP file content type for HTTP request

Tags: ios, http, nsurlrequest

I am sending a zip file to server via HTTPREQUEST. What should be the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) HTTP header *value* for this kind of file?

The file is a ZIP archive that contains images on type PNG.

Thanks

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
.zip    application/zip, application/octet-stream
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a single value or a choice of several?

Comment: This won't guarantee you a `zip` file at all. According to the [WC3 specifications](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) this will be intrepreted as: *"I prefer a `application/zip` content type, but if you cannot deliver this an `application/octet-stream` (file stream) is also fine".*

Comment: Also seen application/x-zip-compressed

Comment: `application/x-zip-compressed` sound like some custom header for specific system. `application/zip, application/octet-stream` are common.

Answer (score 59):

The standard MIME type for ZIP files is `application/zip`. The types for the files inside the ZIP does not matter for the MIME type.

As always, it ultimately depends on your server setup.

Answer (score 4):

```
[request setValue:@"application/zip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the MIME type for a file, you can use the following code:

```
- (NSString *)mimeTypeForPath:(NSString *)path
{
    // get a mime type for an extension using MobileCoreServices.framework

    CFStringRef extension = (__bridge CFStringRef)[path pathExtension];
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, extension, NULL);
    assert(UTI != NULL);

    NSString *mimetype = CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType));
    assert(mimetype != NULL);

    CFRelease(UTI);

    return mimetype;
}
```

In the case of a ZIP file, this will return `application/zip`.