# Wrong MIME-Type for uploaded ZIP files

Tags: php, linux, windows, zip, mime

How do I handle MIME-Type validation of an uploaded ZIP file in both Linux and Windows environments?

I created a testing purposes ZIP file and downloaded another one (first Google result) and use them as arguments of the following code:

```
$finfo = new finfo( FILEINFO_MIME );

echo $finfo -> file( 'benchmark.zip' ), '<br />', $finfo -> file( 'css3menu.zip' ), '<br />';

echo mime_content_type( 'benchmark.zip' ), '<br />', mime_content_type( 'css3menu.zip' );
```

It reported me:

```
application/zip; charset=binary
application/zip; charset=binary
application/zip
application/zip
```

In both environments, Linux, using Apache, and Windows, with PHP built-in webserver.

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027582/753531) I also considered **application/octet-stream** as valid so I added them both to my Upload Handler.

But the upload failed, reporting me invalid file type :(

I checked everything and it was correct, so I decided to isolate the problem with the most basic upload implementation possible (together with that debugging code):

```
if( isset( $_POST['button'] ) ) {

    print '<pre>'; print_r( $_FILES );

    $finfo = new finfo( FILEINFO_MIME );

    echo $finfo -> file( 'benchmark.zip' ), '<br />', $finfo -> file( 'css3menu.zip' ), '<br />';

    echo mime_content_type( 'benchmark.zip' ), '<br />', mime_content_type( 'css3menu.zip' ), '<br />';
}

?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost/test.php" method="post">

<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" />

<input type="submit" name="button" value="Send" />

</form>
```

The MIME-Type reported by FileInfo and mime_content_type() were the same as before, but the **type** index in $_FILES returned **application/vnd.zend.serverconfig** in Linux environment and the less desirable, although valid, **application/octet-stream** in Windows.

Any ideas of why this is happening?

One thing that worth to mention is I'm new in Linux environment so I didn't know how to setup a webserver so, at first, I installed Zend Server but later I uninstalled it completelly and reinstall everything manually using apt-get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding that the **type** index is provided by the browser and not by PHP I tested in Google Chrome and got the correct **application/zip**

So I Google'd how to fix this issue in Firefox, the browser I was testing before, and all I needed to do was delete the **mimeTypes.rdf** file in the profile folder located in *~/.mozilla/firefox/*

Comment: On Firefox 48.0, and OSX, the mimeTypes.rdf file is located here:

Comment: I've just found a zip file with the mime type 'application/x-zip-compressed'.