# MIME types in uploading a file

Tags: php, zip, mime-types, uploading, rar

I am getting an error because of the file extension while uploading a `.rar` or a `.zip`. Here is part of my code:

```
$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$ext_permitidas = array('doc','docx','xls','xlsx','zip','rar','ppt','pptx','pdf');
$partes_nombre = explode('.', $nombre);
$extension = end( $partes_nombre );
$ext_correcta = in_array($extension, $ext_permitidas);
$tipo_correcto = preg_match('/^(application\/(msword|x-rar-compressed|zip|pdf)|application\/vnd\.(ms-excel|ms-powerpoint|openxmlformats-officedocument\.(wordprocessingml\.document|spreadsheetml\.sheet|presentationml\.presentation)))$/', $tipo);
if( $ext_correcta && $tipo_correcto){
#do stuff
}else{
echo 'Invalid file <br><a href="../../../login.php">Return</a> ';
echo $tipo;
}
```

When I upload the `.zip/.rar` file I get an error and `$tipo` is `application/octet-stream`.
One solution I have found for `.zip` is to put that `octet-stream` instead of `.zip` and `.rar` but inexplicably it only works for `.zip`... Anyway, I prefer not to put `octet-stream` becasue it also include `.exe` files.

How could I get it working?

EDIT: my question differs from that one: [.rar, .zip files MIME Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977544/rar-zip-files-mime-type) in the point that I want to upload more file extensions that only `.rar` and `.zip` and in the point that I have tryed that mime types:

```
.rar    application/x-rar-compressed, application/octet-stream
.zip    application/zip, application/octet-stream
```

but I got errors in both of them. I have also tryed that:

```
application/octet-stream
```

but it only works for `.zip` files

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7027582/4350275

Comment: possible duplicate of [.rar, .zip files MIME Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977544/rar-zip-files-mime-type)