# PHP Upload tar.gz, tgz file validation

Tags: php, file-upload, gzip

I am trying to validate if uploaded file is tgz/tar.gz (not just extension name). I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977544/rar-zip-files-mime-type) for RAR and ZIP file but cannot find anything similar for GZIP.

Thanks...

Comment: `tgz mime type` in google shows a lot of variants. Internet is not a stackoverflow only.

Comment: I cant use mime type because I am posting form with name, pass, file. So i need to check file binnary